# RegEx for exact word search starting with Umlaut

Tags: javascript, html, regex, parsing

I am slowly getting a bit frustrated with regex and German Umlaute. For a speech reader function, I need to get each single word, wrap each word in a span-tag with an index and so. It all works fine so far. But as soon as a word starts with a German Umlaut it fails.

Here is an example text:

> Touch-Screen ist Englisch und wird Tatsch-Skrien ausgesprochen.
> Übersetzt bedeutet Touchscreen Berührungsbildschirm. Es ist ein
> berührungsempfindlicher Bildschirm. Zur Bedienung muss man mit dem
> Finger die Oberfläche des Bildschirms berühren.

And this is the regular expression to find the word "Übersetzt":

```
/\b(Übersetzt)\b(?![^<span.*>]*<\/span>)/
```

The span-tag part is needed, since each word will get wrapped in `<span id="SOME_ID">word</span>`.
So to prevent finding the same word twice, this will exclude those already span-tag wrapped words.

But it fails with words starting with an Umlaut. I added other words starting with an Umlaut, and they all failed. If an Umlaut is somewhere in the middle, it doesn't matter. But as soon as a word starts with an Umlaut, it just doesn't work. Maybe someone has a suggestion what I am missing here. Thanks for any advice or help.

I tried figuring out a solution using https://regexr.com/. But it didn't help. Even tried to use \u00dc instead of Ü didn't help in this regex.

Comment: `/(?<=\P{L})(Übersetzt)(?=\P{L})/u`. I’m not comfortable seeing HTML tags in a regular expression. There are much better alternatives, using DOM APIs.

Comment: @SebastianSimon
Thanks so much! That saved me a lot of trial and error with regexr. I know it is not the best way. But it was the quickest way to implement text highlighting using the speech synthesis. Especially since I don't know how the final styling highlighting will look like. So each word has an ID and a class for highlighting.